# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "functie" does not exist (table DOES exist)

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm practicing on creating an API with Django and a Postgres DB. I'm trying to do a raw query (as this is a requirement) but I keep getting an error saying the table doesn't exist. I've set up an APIView for this, which for 1 table actually does work, but the same thing doesn't work for the other. Here's my code:

```
class RetrieveEmployee(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    data = user.objects.raw("SELECT 1 as id FROM user", [])
    print(data.query)
    serializer = serializers.EmployeeSerializer(data, many=True)
    return Response({"employee": serializer.data})
```

^ This one does work. This is the output in the console when I do a GET request to this endpoint:

```
[08/Jan/2021 13:20:04] "GET /employeeAPIVIEW HTTP/1.1" 301 0
SELECT 1 as id FROM user
[08/Jan/2021 13:20:05] "GET /employeeAPIVIEW/ HTTP/1.1" 200 133
```

This one doesn't work:

```
class RetrieveRole(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    data = functie.objects.raw("SELECT 1 as id FROM functie", [])
    print(data.query)
    serializer = serializers.RoleSerializer(data, many=True)
    return Response({"role": serializer.data})
```

This is what I get from the console:

```
SELECT 1 as id FROM functie
Internal Server Error: /roleAPIVIEW/
Traceback [...]
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "functie" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT 1 as id FROM functie
                        ^
[08/Jan/2021 12:57:43] "GET /roleAPIVIEW/ HTTP/1.1" 500 154696
```

However, both tables 'user' and 'functie' do exist in my Postgres DB. Why does psycopg2 keep saying the relation doesn't exist? I've checked everywhere on spelling mistakes.

[Image: tables overview in Postgres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlJKV.png)

Comment: Hi Wes,
It's difficult to say based on the code snippets you've provided. Have you brought the functie object into your script like you must've done with user?

Comment: @patrick.mchugh4 Hi Patrick, thanks for the reply. Not sure what you mean, but I configured it the same way I did with 'user'. Weird thing is when I run makemigrations > migrate, it does create the table for me, but I just can't query it because it can't find it

Comment: In the examples you've provided you're accessing the table objects:
user.objects.... and functie.objects..., which I'm assuming inherit from Django's model.Model class (so should ideally be capitalised, but that's just me being pedantic to standard Python formatting). Do you import these into the scripts that you're attempting to access them (from models import user, funcite)?

Comment: Per here [Raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) you need to do `"SELECT 1 as id FROM testDb_functie"`. I'm guessing the `user` query works because there is a table named `user` in the database.